# Cygwin: "boost/filesystem.hpp: No such file or directory compilation terminated."

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I get this error when I'm using Cygwin on a "makefile":

`"boost/filesystem.hpp: No such file or directory compilation terminated."`

This is everything that's inside the "makefile":

`mnisten: src/main.cpp g++ -Wall -O2 -lboost_filesystem-mt -std=c++0x -o mnisten src/main.cpp`

And inside the "main.cpp" file, this is the line of code that the error message is referring to:

`#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>`

First I tried to put the "boost" folder (containing "filesystem.hpp") inside the "src" folder, but the error message was unchanged, I still got the same error message.

Then I changed the "include" code inside "main.cpp" to: 
`#include <filesystem.hpp>`

I also copied the "filesystem.hpp" file into the root of the "src" folder, and surprisingly this worked. I got a new error, but I got past the "include" part.

I find it very confusing that it I get an error when the file is in a folder, but when it is in the root of the "src" folder it works.

**Any suggestions on how I can get it to work when the file is inside the "boost" folder?**

(I downloaded the the "filesystem.hpp" since it was not included)

Comment: have you installed the cygwin package `libboost-devel` that includes filesystem.hpp ?

Comment: That worked, Thanks. Now I got an error about "opencv/cv.hpp", do you happen to know the name of the package that includes "cv.hpp" as well?

Answer (score 2):

To find the cygwin package that contains a given file you can use `cygcheck -p`

```
$ cygcheck -p boost/filesystem.hpp
Found 6 matches for boost/filesystem.hpp
libboost-devel-1.60.0-1 - libboost-devel: Boost C++ libraries (installed binaries and support files)
libboost-devel-1.60.0-2 - libboost-devel: Boost C++ libraries (installed binaries and support files)
mingw64-i686-boost-1.60.0-1 - mingw64-i686-boost: Boost C++ libraries for Win32 toolchain (installed binaries and support files)
mingw64-i686-boost-1.60.0-2 - mingw64-i686-boost: Boost C++ libraries for Win32 toolchain (installed binaries and support files)
mingw64-x86_64-boost-1.60.0-1 - mingw64-x86_64-boost: Boost C++ libraries for Win64 toolchain (installed binaries and support files)
mingw64-x86_64-boost-1.60.0-2 - mingw64-x86_64-boost: Boost C++ libraries for Win64 toolchain (installed binaries and support files)
```

so you need to install `libboost-devel` as you are not crosscompiling for mingw64.
Similar for

```
$ cygcheck -p opencv/cv.hpp
Found 1 matches for opencv/cv.hpp
libopencv-devel-2.4.11-1 - libopencv-devel: Real-time computer vision library (development) (installed binaries and support files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have any boost installed in your system. I got this error and solved by installing it.

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```